# Why "DataBase Connections" mapped to "Dataset DataBase Connections" in ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, arccatalog

I am trying to Export data from a geodatabase by a existed sde file(created by ArcCatalog),
the Error Messges:

> Executing: ExportCAD 'DataBase Connections\Connection to
>   GIS-WANG.sde\SDE.water\SDE.ControlValve' DWG_R2010 D:\117.DWG
>   Ignore_Filenames_in_Tables Overwrite_Existing_Files # Start Time: Thu
>   Oct 13 16:46:59 2011 ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (ExportCAD).
>   Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000732: Input Features: ***Dataset
>   'DataBase Connections***\Connection to
>   GIS-WANG.sde\SDE.water\SDE.ControlValve' does not exist or is not
>   supported Failed to execute (ExportCAD). Failed at Thu Oct 13 16:46:59
>   2011 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds)

Why "DataBase Connections" mapped to "Dataset DataBase Connections"?

Comment: It's not, you're misreading the error message. Does the feature class referenced by that path exist? Also, try "Database Connections" instead of "DataBase Connections".

Comment: This is a sample for "Database Connections"；the "Database Connections" is executed by arccatalog.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is occuring, because the  script does not know where "DataBase Connections" is. (ArcCatlog/ArcMAP know where it is, and this is why, it works if you use the same syntax within these applications. This is one my pet peeves when working with ArcGIS)

The actual SDE connection  file  is usually in %appdata%/ESRI/ArcCatlog .. or something similar.

What I usually do, is either give the entire path to the .sde file, or copy the .sde file to some location, and use that path in the script.

For example, I'll copy the .sde file from the above location, to say D:\Con and then use the following script

```
ExportCAD 'D:\Con\Connection to GIS-WANG.sde\SDE.water\SDE.ControlValve' DWG_R2010 D:\117.DWG Ignore_Filenames_in_Tables Overwrite_Existing_Files
```

Comment: for database connections ,How to set the executed path of the script  in arccatalog or arcmap ?

Comment: @user509028 Are you running the script within ArcMap/ArcCatalog, or running the tool?

Comment: Export data to geodatabase By the ArcToolbox's tool in ArcCatalog 10, (*.sde) file is created by the Database Connections of ArcCatalog 10